# How to debug "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to calculate the total by selecting the number of tickets and multiplying it by 100$.

Please see link below for the actual page.

```
<script>

     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       function compute() {
           var a =  jQuery('#nb_billet').val();
           var b = 100
           var total = a * b;
            jQuery('#total').val(total);
         }

        jQuery('#a, #b').change(compute);
              });
</script>
```

[External website](http://fondationmarieclarac.org/fr/de-beaux-prix-pour-une-bonne-cause/).

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: the error occurs in the init.js document line 487 $(document).click(function(){
  $('.search-module-opened, .cart-module-opened').hide();
 e.preventDefault();

Comment: What is intit.js?  A 3rd party JS library, or something you've written?

Comment: 3rd party js library included with the theme

Comment: please make your post self contained. it will be easier to get an answer, and will not look like a disguised spam for a charity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code i just checked and its working!

```
      var a =  jQuery('#a').val();
      var b = 100
      var total = a * b;
      jQuery('#total').text(total);
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank everything is working fine

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Glad i could help. Could you vote up or accept my answer!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi colon on the following line:

```
var b = 100
```

should be

```
var b = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code e.preventDefault() is used whereas 'e' is not passed in the anonymous function.

[image: e is not defined, thats the error]

So please pass 'e' in the function.

revised code:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
      $('.search-module-opened, .cart-module-opened').hide();
      e.preventDefault();
   });
```

Comment: it worked!!! shoukran Kamal I dont see the error.
However, my code of calculating the total doesn't work

Comment: I figured out the solution.. First thing if you have resolved 'e' error then next step should be to use the following code:

jQuery('#total').text(total)

Since, #total is span it doesn't has val attribute, so u need to use text property to set any value.

Please accept the answer, if it works!

Comment: i tried with the text attribute and the total is now showing Nan

Comment: So basically NaN is (Not a number) error, means your multiplication is not happening. 

It  means either of your value a or b is not coming fine..

So please check what value you get in a and b by console.log.

and if both values are fine. you can try to parse them to integer seperately as follows:

parseInt(a) * parseInt(b).

Comment: I also took a look following code me gives 'undefined'.

jQuery('#nb_billet').val();

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

Don't use `val()`, rather use `text()`:

```
    jQuery('#total').text(total)
```